# trouble with SmartThreadPool sending Array

Tags: c#, arrays, threadpool

If I execute this code:

```
var threads = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
var stp = new SmartThreadPool(1000, threads, threads);
for (int i = 0; i < acclength; i++)
{
    stp.QueueWorkItem(openThread, accs[i, 0], accs[i, 1]);
}
stp.WaitForIdle();
stp.Shutdown();
```

I won't receive the whole array in the function `openThread()`.
One time I receive the last element end else I won't receive anything just empty strings.

Comment: What is the `SmartThreadPool` class?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: SmartThreadPool class is this one bassicly the standar libary with some extras, https://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note that it's also not a class that everyone knows about. If you can reproduce your problem with the standard `ThreadPool` class, that would get you more answers.